# Fancybox is hidding some element on page

Tags: html, css, fancybox

on my website, i click on some element that have the optioin to open some page using FancyBox, then this action is hidding my logo, and i don't know why...

can see here: http://notoriaclub.com.br/?sim (Click on DJS, then click on the DJ Photo).

Here is my LOGO code:

```
<div id="logo">
    <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html">Notória Club</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#logo{
    width: 990px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top:17px;
    left: 23px;
    width: 214px;
    height: 165px;
    z-index: 99;
}
.logo a{
    display: block;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: 214px;
    height: 165px;
    background:url(../imagens/logo_notoria.png) no-repeat;
}
```

And my fancyBox Setup:

```
$(".various").fancybox({
                maxWidth    : 800,
                maxHeight   : 600,
                fitToView   : false,
                width       : '500px',
                height      : '250px',
                autoSize    : false,
                closeClick  : false,
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none'
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What's Going On

`#logo` has a height of `0`. For some reason, clicking the fancy box is causing it to have `overflow:hidden;` applied as well. There are several ways to fix the issue. We could apply height to `#logo`, but then we'd have to know the height, and it would be one more thing to change if you ever change the logo. Easier is just to change `.logo` to `position:relative` instead of `position:absolute`.

## Code

#### Change:

```
.logo{
    position: absolute;
    top:17px;
    left: 23px;
    width: 214px;
    height: 165px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

#### To:

```
.logo{
    position: relative;
    top:17px;
    left: 23px;
    width: 214px;
    height: 165px;
    z-index: 99;
}
```